# Angular - How to dynamically show replies to a comment

Tags: angular

I have a post, a post has many comments and a comment can have many replies.

When the post is viewed the initial comments are loaded with it. Under each comment there is a button which says "Show replies" similar to youtube. How do i dynamically add dom elements so that i can show the replies of a comment.

I have looked at
1. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
2. ViewChild

But i don't understand the difference between the two? Which one should i use or how else should i approach a solution for my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you could try to use a simple ***ngIf** for the replies. Let's say your reply list is capsuled in an own component, something like *reply-list.component*. Under every comment you have two things: a) *reply-list.component* and b) a *button* to show those comments. Initially hide the *reply-list.component* with a simple boolean value and an *ngIf on the *reply-list.component*. This may look something like this:

```
<reply-list *ngIf="showReplies" [commentId]="comment.id"></reply-list>
<button *ngIf="!showReplies" (click)="showReplies()></button>
```

*ngIf prevents the component from beeing created (if I'm not mistaken) so the replies are not shown, the component is not even created. With the button you could simply switch the `showReplies` boolean to true and the component is created. Load all the replies of the comment in the `ngOnInit` function of the component and they are dynamically created right in the spot.

Comment: Ah that explains it nicely. the <reply-list> is just added using a simple import statement? or is that to do with ViewChild?

Comment: It's a simple component, so you don't even have to import it, you just have to create it and declare it in your module where your post/comment components are also declared. ViewChild is not need in this solution here at all which I think makes it a bit easier.

Comment: In addition, could this solution be used for nested replies? A comment has a reply, and the reply has a reply. BTW a reply is the same as a  comment in my schema. Except a reply has a parent_id to the parent comment.

Comment: Yes, I thought that you probably want to load the replies only after the button was pressed. To get the replies from your backend you probably need to know the commentId of the replies to load. In this case you can use angulars *input* variables to give every reply-list.component that is created the commentId that it needs to load its replies to.

Comment: Yes, nested replies or in your case comments could be possible too. Let's just say a comment as a component has a text, a button to show replies and a list of replies (which are loaded after the button was pressed). This could be your main template of how a comment or a reply looks like. Initially your replies are just an empty list and when you press the button of the comment you load your replies inside a function from the backend. Instead of a reply-list.component you could have use *ngFor and use a <comment></comment> component instead. I think that is what @Llai proposed.

Comment: Yeah i have a problem with the showReplies variable and how to make it dynamic for each comment. A simple boolean shows all replies for every comment which i dont want that AND setting showReplies to a specific comment id will hide previously shown replies which i dont want either. I need something like showReplies[comment._id] but i get cannot read property of 123 of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159813/discussion-between-benedikt-schmidt-and-khan).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is something like

```
comments = [
    {
        comment: '...',
        showReplies: false,
        replies: [
            {
                comment: '...',
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
];
```

I would use a nested ngFor

```
<comment *ngFor="let comment of comments">
    <ng-container *ngIf="comment.showReplies">
        <reply *ngFor="let reply of comment.replies">
            ...
        </reply>
    </ng-container>
</comment>
```

And toggle the `showReplies` flag to render the replies.

Comment: Im not loading in the reply data, only when the button is clicked a call is made to the server to get the replies

Comment: @KHAN In that case you can still store replies in this structure and make the ngIf statement `*ngIf="comment.replies"` or set the `showReplies` flag to true after you receive the replies data.

Comment: So you would initially leave the replies list empty and when pressing the button under a comment you would then load them and set them as its replies attribute, correct? That should be working too I guess.

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt correct. This would keep the replies with their associated comment

Comment: I think that's good, then you could do nested replies easier by just assuming they are all some sort of comment. Initially the list is empty and when the button is pressed, the replies are loaded and shown in the DOM after the *ngIf is now true. Then the replies could also be of type `comment.component` and have the same structure as children again. I like it.